# `f :: a -> IO ()` evaluation in do thread : Haskell

Tags: haskell

This is a repost of my previous question(deleted by myself) since I considered it would be adequate to change the focus by presenting the sample code below.

Basically, I try to implement **a** Functor that takes a function such as `id`, `\a -> a + 1` or even `print` .

So the function type can be

`f :: a -> b`

`f :: a -> IO ()`

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad.Primitive (PrimMonad (PrimState))
import qualified Data.Vector.Mutable as M
import System.IO.Error (isDoesNotExistErrorType)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let ioA = io (5 :: Int)
  let f = print
  --  f = \a -> a + 1
  let ioB = someFunctor f ioA

  ioB

  print "done"

data R a = R
  { val :: M.MVector (PrimState IO) a
  }

io :: a -> IO (R a)
io = \a -> do
  val <- M.new 1
  M.write val 0 a
  return $ R val

_val :: R a -> IO a
_val = \ra -> M.read (val ra) 0

someFunctor :: Show a => (a -> b) -> IO (R a) -> IO (R b)
someFunctor = \f -> \ioA -> do
  print "-- someFunctor"

  val <- ioA >>= _val
  print val --works    5
  let ioB = io $ f val

  --here, I want to actually `print val` when `f == print`
  return $ f val

  ioB
```

Output

```
"-- someFunctor"
5
"done"
```

The current sample code woks without errors, and what  I want to achieve is to evaluate

`f val`

where

1. `f val` is the value wrapped into the new container `ioB`: `io $ f val`
2. However, due to the lazy-evaluation strategy of Haskell or some other reason, when `f == print`, this is not actually performed, so the `val` is not printed against my expectation.
3. So far, I did `return $ f val`, but this does not work unlike the working `print val`.
4. Just `f val` in `do` thread doesn't go well because `f` can be `id` and in that case, it's not `IO` type. Type mismatch. The compiler smartly generates an error here thanksfully.
5. So, my question is what is the *generic* way to implement `f val` to be evaluated when `f == print` `f :: a -> IO ()`?

Comment: `R` ≈ [`IORef`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-IORef.html)?

Comment: And I think you should have `someFunctor :: Show a => (a -> IO b) -> R a -> IO (R b)` instead of your current signature. If not, explain why.

Comment: 1. It's not Functor, 2. `(a -> IO b)` does fit to `id` or other `(a -> b)` functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do `IO`, you have to admit you're doing `IO`.

```
someFunctor :: Show a => (a -> IO b) -> IO (R a) -> IO (R b)
someFunctor = \f -> \ioA -> do
    {- ... -}
    b <- f val
    io b
```

You can lift non-`IO` functions to `IO` ones with `return`, as in

```
someFunctor (return . id)
```

Comment: Great, it works! Thanks. So the type `(a -> b)` not `a -> IO b` prevents to work as IO. I'm from TypeScript, so this behavior is new..

Comment: @Functor That's... sort of right, but not quite. If a function accepts something of type `a -> b`, you can give it a function that returns an `IO` action; but you can be sure that the resulting `IO` action is produced only, and not executed. Compare `main = print 3; return ()` and ```main = let x = print 3 in x `seq` return ()```. The former both produces and executes the `print 3` action; the latter produces but does not execute it.

Comment: OK, thanks for your deeper elaboration, very informative. One more confirmation I would like, but I will create a new Q.

Comment: My extended Q is [if typeOf `f` == `io` then `f` else `return . f` in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71021454/if-typeof-f-io-then-f-else-return-f-in-haskell) Thanks :)