# if typeOf f == io then f else return . f in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Related to

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71020780/17053359

We can lift non-`IO` functions : `f` to `IO` ones with `return`, as in

```
return . f
```

and now, I want to make this `f` generic including `IO`

```
f :: A -> IO A -- not IO to IO
f :: IO a -> IO a -- (no change, `id` instead of `return`)
```

in other words:

if typeOf `f` == `io` then `f`

else `return . f`

What would the code be in Haskell?

EDIT:

```js
console.log(
 Object(1)
);

console.log(
 Object(Object(1))
);

console.log(
 Object(Object(Object(1)))
);
```

Comment: I don't know if this *can* be done -- maybe, with enough type families and `TypeRep`s -- but it certainly *shouldn't* be done. Why do you think you need this?

Comment: My basic idea is so-called idempotency.  `f` ->`IO(f)` ->`IO(f)` ->`IO(f)` ->`IO(f)` It's the same structure of that Monads prevents the nested structure after the bind/map.

Comment: What would the type signature of such function be. In Haskell everything needs to have a type. But regardless, IMHO it is not a good idea either: treating an `IO` as "special" does not make much sense.

Comment: @Functor Yes, I understand the effect you're going for; what I don't understand is why. Can you lead me down a garden path starting from something I obviously want to do and gradually solving problem after problem until only this one is left?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It's just a type and not special at all, See my Edit of Q. In JS, there is a function `Object` which can lift primitive values to Object, but never nesting. Same principle and in Math, it's just idempotent.

Comment: @Daniel Wagner The reason I wonder this is at least to me, `IO` nesting is simply bothersome, and I think `IO` is always non-nest `IO` unlike `IO(IO a)`.  So I simply want to know if there is such a function on `return`. Currently, `return` does n ot prevent nesting `IO` correct?

Comment: `IO` is not idempotent in this manner. An `IO (IO a)` is an `IO` action that, when executed, produces another `IO` action that may or may not be executed by the caller. See [my answer to *Why will a IO nested in other monads not execute? Is there a way to force them to?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42404828/2751851) for some discussion and a concrete example.

Comment: @duplode Great thanks.

Comment: Okay, you don't want an `IO (IO a)`. Fine. But why do you need to apply the *same* function to an `Int` as to an `IO Int`? Why not have two different functions? What is the scenario where you are writing a program and *don't know* whether the thing you're looking at is an `IO` action or not?

Comment: It's just for simplicity. Either way, I needed to confirm the nest/flat  `IO` situation in Haskell. Now I'm reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53939191/how-to-flatten-io-io and this helps. Thanks.

Comment: Okay. If the goal is simplicity, then I assure you that the thing you are asking for is *much less simple* than using different functions to consume `Int`s and `IO Int`s.

Comment: I can't help but feeling that if you posted a concrete example of a situation where you think you need to do this, we'd be able to tell you why you should be doing something else instead (and more importantly, *what* that something should be).

Comment: Thanks, guys, either way, I declined to use this approach.

Answer (score 3):

You almost definitely *do not* actually want to do this. The amount of type level hackery required for this should already scare you away and this is really not how Monads are supposed to be used.

Purely for educational purposes, this is how you could define a function `pureish`, that behaves just like `return` if the argument *is not* of type `IO a` and just like `id` if the argument *is* of type `IO a`.

```hs
type family PureishResult a where
    PureishResult (IO a) = a
    PureishResult a = a

class Pureish p where
    pureish :: p -> IO (PureishResult p)

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} (PureishResult a ~ a) => Pureish a where
    pureish = pure

instance Pureish (IO a) where
    pureish = id
```

Don't say I didn't warn you!

Answer (score 2):

Here's another version of [Prophet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71022478/1477667), without overlapping instances.

```
{-# language MultiParamTypeClasses, DataKinds, KindSignatures, TypeFamilies, TypeApplications, ScopedTypeVariables, AllowAmbiguousTypes, FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts #-}

type family GetUnderlying a where
  GetUnderlying (IO a) = a
  GetUnderlying a = a

type family IsIO a where
  IsIO (IO _) = True
  IsIO _ = False

class Pureish (isIO :: Bool) u a where
  pureish' :: a -> IO u

instance Pureish False u u where
  pureish' = pure

instance Pureish True u (IO u) where
  pureish' = id

pureish :: forall a u. (Pureish (IsIO a) u a, u ~ GetUnderlying a) => a -> IO u
pureish = pureish' @(IsIO a)
```

Answer (score -5):

Answered by myself.

I totally have no idea what's wrong with my question, perhaps my way to ask is not sufficient. At least, I have mentioned idempotency and with my sample snippet JS. but here is my simple solution.

```
(+++) :: (a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> a -> c
(+++) = flip (.)

infixl 9 +++

someFunctor :: Show a => (a -> IO b) -> IO (R a) -> IO (R b)
someFunctor = \f -> \ioA -> do
  print "-- someFunctor"

  val <- ioA >>= _val

  b <- (f +++ return +++ join) val

  io b
```

based on the code of my previous Q&A:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71020780/17053359

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question that you asked. At no point in that code are you accepting a value that may or may not be an `IO` and then doing something different based on whether or not it is.

Comment: The type part is working right now.

Comment: `f +++ return +++ join` is required to be exactly the same as `f` by the monad laws. And once you do that rewrite, you get back to exactly the code shown in the linked Q&A, namely `b <- f val`...

Comment: It's not the same as `f` because `join` has the "safety-net" feature that never wrap off to the naked level. Once it's wrapped in Monad, `join` can't take out the naked value from the box.

Comment: by the way, in Monad law, the `f` is a Monad function. `a -> M b`. The `f` here is `a -> b` and  `(a -> b) -> IO (a -> b)`

Comment: In the definition of `someFunctor` here, `f` is `a -> IO b`, as specified by the type signature.

Comment: @duplode It's another problem, in fact, my next question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71025508/union-type-a-b-io-b-in-haskell

Comment: It is the same as `f`. Try proving me wrong. If you can find any code where replacing `f +++ return +++ join` in the body of `someFunctor` with `f` changes the behavior, I'd very much like to see it. I have no idea what this "safety net" you're talking about is referring to. Additionally, your claim that "`f ` here is `a -> b`" is not correct: the type signature for `someFunctor` very clearly states that its first argument is `a -> IO b`.

Comment: @DanielWagner Well you are right, it's `(a -> IO b)` and `a -> b`. I misunderstood as if `IO (a -> b)`