# Union type (a -> b | IO b) in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I need to define a Union Type which the set of the type includes

`a -> b` **OR** `a -> IO b`

`a -> b` `||` `a -> IO b`

or

`a -> b | IO b`

`foo :: (a -> b | IO b) -> IO (R a) -> IO (R b)`

I tried `data unionType b = b | IO b` that does not work.

```
Not a data constructor: ‘b’parser
No quick fixes available
```

Is it possible in Haskell?

Comment: I know it seems like we're smart here, and can figure it out without knowing anything else, but it's still polite to include *observed behavior, expected behavior,* and any *error messages* you are getting, in your post.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well, I think the question is concise enough and I also added the proof element of "what I've tried so far". I know someone here don't like the "short question" but what did you feel not "polite"? Length of the question?

Comment: Q&A is not a Bug report, so *observed behavior, expected behavior, and any error messages* does not fit the quesion formatl.

Comment: The thing is, this is an instance of a broader very common beginner question. In order to provide an answer that really addresses the challenges you're facing, we need to understand what they are. What is your current understanding? Why did you end up thinking that? Is there an improvement we can make to standard introductory materials that will make it easier for others in the future?

Comment: @Carl In my opinion, it'd depend on POV. I am rather an experienced functional programmer in TypeScript (Yes this is possible in TS) and wrote books in Japanese. Here I don't know why a person who asks quesions must prove their programming ability for this simple question. This quesiton is indepndent of the further application.

Comment: I would be extremely surprised to see anything of this type in a professional Haskell application.  The idiomatic approach is to _always_ return `IO b`, whether or not any IO actually occurred.  While it's possible to do this, it wouldn't be good practice.

Comment: Possibly relevant: [*Why do We Need Sum Types?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40620913/2751851)

Comment: Yes it actually always return `IO (R a) -> IO (R b)` The code simply require to accept both `a -> b` and `a -> IO b` What's wrong with this in a professional Hakell applications?

Comment: @Functor As we've tried to explain on your previous two questions: the thing that's wrong with it is that it leads to very complicated code, whereas the alternative leads to simple code. Instead of this complicated, unidiomatic thing, simply accept an `a -> IO b`, and leave it to your caller to turn its `a -> b` into an `a -> IO b` before calling your function.

Comment: @DanielWagner Well, thanks for your patience, but I must disagree with your opinion to force what the software design should be. If a function can be genric not to bother caller. It should be done inside of the function to avoid complexity. Your approach occurs complexity explostion.

Comment: Having programmed in Haskell professionally for almost a decade now, I can confidently say that empirically, the approach I describe does not cause complexity explosion.

Comment: @DanielWagner Ok, let me confirm, please. Do you suggest to prepare 2 functions(functors) for `f :: a -> b` and `f:: a -> IO b`  ?

Comment: @Functor No, just one function; `foo :: (a -> IO b) -> IO (R a) -> IO (R b)`. In fact, I would almost certainly additionally drop the `IO` from the other input, making it `foo :: (a -> IO b) -> R a -> IO (R b)`, except in very unusual circumstances.

Comment: @DanielWagner IMO, to modify every pure function to a -> IO a is so much problematic and unacceptable, so I decided to have 2 separated functions for non-IO and IO. This method works and is simple enough. Dropping the `IO` from the other input binds function within `do` thread, and limit the usage, so I won't do that. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Functor If you have a function `f`, then `pure . f` has the appropriate type. I think you will find that, as you use Haskell more, having a flexible function and using something like `(pure .)` at the call-site when needed introduces *much* less complexity. It is often better to use small, flexible/generic functions in combination rather than many specialized functions. Right now, it feels like you are trying to work *against* the language (for instance, here you are actively avoiding the flexibility the language provides). This usually causes more pain, regardless of the language.

Comment: @Functor I agree, modifying every pure function to actually claim to do `IO` would indeed be problematic. Instead, when you have a pure function that needs to be used in a monadic context, use `return` (or `pure` -- take a guess why it's named that) to adapt it on the spot, without changing its source. Yes, dropping `IO` from the other input requires the caller to bind the output of their `IO` action. This is usually what you want, anyway, as it gives you greater control over when side effects are done (and how many times, more to the point).

Comment: @DavidYoung Thanks, I understand it's easy to have it by composing the function. I will study more.

Comment: @DanielWagner Thanks again, I sort of understand now why you suggest `foo :: (a -> IO b) -> R a -> IO (R b)`; however. for non-IO function, I think `foo :: (a -> IO b) -> R a -> R b)` is simpler, but hard to implement to make it work as expected.

Answer (score 5):

In Haskell, a *sum type* (the standard term for a disjoint union type) requires explicit "constructors" for its components, so you need to write something like:

```
data BarType b = BarPure b | BarIO (IO b)
```

This defines a type `BarType`, and it also defines constructors `BarPure` and `BarIO` for use in constructing values of this type:

```
val1, val2 :: BarType String
val1 = BarPure "pure"
val2 = BarIO getLine
```

and consuming values of this type via case-matching:

```
runBar :: BarType b -> IO b
runBar barb = case barb of
  BarPure s -> pure s
  BarIO act -> act
```

Comment: ...but if all you're going to do is accept one of these as a function argument, then you might as well write `barPure = return; barIO = id` and accept an `IO b` instead of a `BarType b`.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues: On the one hand your type must be upper-case, that is `UnionType`. Second, you need to define *type constructors* to be able to create a value of said `data` type. So the closest would be e.g.

```
data UnionType b = Left b | Right (IO b)
```

Here I chose the arbitrary names `Left` and `Right` for the constructors, but you can use any you like.

If the `Left`/`Right` constructors seem familiar to you, that is because [`Either`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Either.html) uses these by default, and can do exactly the same with a slightly "cheaper" `type` synonym:

```
type UnionType b = Either b (IO b)
```

Of course in both cases we have to [deconstruct](https://wiki.haskell.org/Constructor)  the type to get to the actual values of `b` and `IO b`.

EDIT: As @leftroundabout mentioned, it is not very convenient to define a `data` type with type constructors called `Left` and `Right`, as these constructors are already used with the built in `Either`.

Comment: Please don't call the constructors `Left` and `Right`. Either simply use `Either b (IO b)` instead of defining any custom data type, which already has the `Left` and `Right` constructors, or define your own and call them different then.

Comment: Thanks, can you answer an alternative you can think of? @leftaroundabout

Comment: @leftaroundabout Thanks for the suggestion, we were thinking the same thing - I just wasn't completely finished the answer yet!